# Negative infinity in Lisp

Tags: lisp, fixnum

I'm looking for the standard way to represent negative infinity in Lisp. Is there a symblic value which is recognised by Lisp's arithmetic functions as less than all other numbers?

Specifically, I'm looking for an elegant way to write the following:

```
(defun largest (lst)
  "Evaluates to the largest number in lst"
  (if (null lst)
    ***negative-inifinity***
    (max (car lst) (largest (cdr lst)))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ANSI Common Lisp has `bignum`, which can used to represent arbitrarily large numbers as long as you have enough space, but it doesn't specify an "infinity" value. Some *implementations* may, but that's not part of the standard.

In your case, I think you've got to rethink your approach based on the purpose of your function: finding the largest number in a list. Trying to find the largest number in an empty list is invalid/nonsense, though, so you want to provide for that case. So you can define a precondition, and if it's not met, return `nil` or raise an error. Which in fact is what the built-in function `max` does.

```
(apply #'max '(1 2 3 4)) => 4
(apply #'max nil) => error
```

---

**EDIT:** As pointed by Rainer Joswig, Common Lisp doesn't allow [arbitrarily long argument lists](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/v_call_a.htm#call-arguments-limit), thus it is best to use `reduce` instead of `apply`.

```
(reduce #'max '(1 2 3 4))
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware max took an arbitrary number of arguments, but that provides an elegant solution.

Comment: Since functions in Common Lisp don't allow arbitrary long argument lists, it is best to replace APPLY with REDUCE. See the value of the variable CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT . An implementation supports up to CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT long argument lists. In your example it would mean that an implementation may fail to compute the maximum on CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT + 1 long lists. Note that this the value of CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT can be as small as 50 (!).

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing like that in ANSI Common Lisp. Common Lisp implementations (and even math applications) differ in their representation of negative infinity.

For example in LispWorks for double floats:

```
CL-USER 23 > (* MOST-NEGATIVE-DOUBLE-FLOAT 10)
-1D++0
```